Error en el segmento PID de la librería HL7 para PHP
Estoy usando la librería HL7. Pero incluso con los ejemplos que hay en Github sale el siguiente error.

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Segment name 'PID|||abcd|' should be 3 characters and in uppercase in... \Aranyasen\HL7\Segment.php on line 39

Si comento dicha validación de las líneas 38 a la 40 y ejecuto el siguiente código:
<?php
  include('ruta_absoluta\Aranyasen\HL7\Message.php');
  use Aranyasen\HL7\Message;

  $message = new Message("MSH|^~\\&|1|\rPID|||abcd|\r");
  
  // Extracting segments and fields from a Message object...
  print_r($message->getSegmentByIndex(0));
  print_r($message->getSegmentByIndex(1));
?>

Obtengo como resultado:
Aranyasen\HL7\Segment Object ( [fields:protected] => Array ( [0] => MSH [1] => ^~\& [2] => 1 ) ) 
Aranyasen\HL7\Segment Object ( [fields:protected] => Array ( [0] => PID|||abcd| ) )

Como se puede observar, el primer segmento está bien, pero en el segundo segmento no se separa el nombre del segmento ni los campos en diferentes elementos, sino que lo interpreta como un único elemento o cadena de texto.
Me pueden indicar, por favor, si estoy haciendo algo mal o es error de la librería?

esta biendo las 3 barras como parte del elemento: "PID|||abcd|"

Finalmente lo resolví con otro método que ofrece la misma librería, quedando de la siguiente manera:
<?php
  include('ruta_absoluta\Aranyasen\HL7\Message.php');
  include('ruta_absoluta\Aranyasen\HL7\Segments\PID.php');

  use Aranyasen\HL7\Message;
  use Aranyasen\HL7\Segments\PID;

  // Segmento MSH en la posición 0
  $message = new Message("MSH|^~\\&|1", ['SEGMENT_ENDING_BAR' => false]);
  
  //Construir el segmento PID
  $pid = new PID();
  $pid->setField(3, 'abcd'); // Agregar los campos necesarios en la posicón deseada
  $message->setSegment($pid, 1); // Agregar el segmento PID en la posición 1 

  // Extraer los segmentos y campos desde el objeto Message...
  print_r($message->getSegmentByIndex(0));
  print_r($message->getSegmentByIndex(1));
?>

Esto me devuelve la información de manera correcta.
Aranyasen\HL7\Segment Object ( [fields:protected] => Array ( [0] => MSH [1] => ^~\& [2] => 1 ) ) 
Aranyasen\HL7\Segment Object ( [fields:protected] => Array ( [0] => PID [1] =>  [2] =>  [3] => abcd ) )

